# Is there any way to validate the performance of a Doc2Vec/ Word2Vec Deep Learning model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am working with the Doc2Vec and Word2Vec deep learning algorithms ([Doc2Vec API  description from Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)). [More description here](http://rare-technologies.com/deep-learning-with-word2vec-and-gensim/)

Currently I am interested in using the `model.n_similarity(wordSet1, wordSet2)` method which basically computes the  cosine similarity between two sets of words.

I am interested in any ways of validating the models performance, not just on the `n_similiarity()` function, but overall how accurate or realistic results can the model provide. Since it performs deep learning, I do not know if there is any ways of knowing how well does it perform.

Are there any techniques that I should look up, then use or is there a data-set that has results and I should compare ?

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thank you.